# Are the Euler Characteristics of noncollapsed manifolds with bounded Ricci curvature uniformly bounded above?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry

For positive number $C>0$, $d>0$, are the Euler Characteristics of n dimensional closed Riemannian manifolds $M$ with diameter $\leqslant d$, $|Ric|\leqslant C$ uniformly bounded?

If this is false, what about the non-collapsed case? i.e. for $v>0$, consider the class of above manifolds that satisfies $vol(M)\geqslant v$.

Comment: For your first question, consider the case that $n$ equals $6$.  Since we do not know whether there are only finitely many deformation types of Calabi-Yau manifolds of complex dimension $3$, it seems unlikely that we can bound the set of possible Euler characteristics.

Comment: Probably you aware of this, but let me notice that it was shown by G. Perelman that the connected sum of any number of $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^2$ (which has arbitrarily large Euler characteristic) carries a Riemannian metric with positive Ricci curvature, diameter 1 and volume bounded away from 0. See his paper "Construction of manifolds of positive Ricci curvature with big volume and large Betti numbers" (1997).

Answer (score 3):

Without a lower volume bound this is false in dimensions 4 and up (and true in dimensions 2, 3). First counterexamples were constructed by Anderson.
It's Theorem 0.4 in "[Hausdorff perturbations of Ricci-flat manifolds and the splitting theorem](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.dmj/1077293864)".

You can take a sequence of flat tori of the form $T^3\times S^1(\epsilon)$ with $\epsilon\to 0$ and do  several surgeries along various $p\times S^1(\epsilon)$ by cutting out $D^3\times S^1$ and gluing back in $S^2\times D^2$. One can put almost Ricci flat metrics on the resulting manifolds by gluing in Schwarzschild Ricci flat metrics on $R^2\times S^2$ because a Schwarzschild metric is asymptotic to $R^3\times S^1$. As $\epsilon\to 0$ you can glue in arbitrary many of these. With a lower volume bound the statement is true in dimension 4 by Andrerson-Cheeger-Naber "[Regularity of Einstein Manifolds and the Codimension 4 Conjecture](https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.6534)". In fact, there is even diffeomorphism finiteness in this case. In dimensions above 4 as far as I know this is an open question but I would guess it's most likely false.